# Where can i buy really long and thin sheets (ie.4000l x 100w x 4mm) of wood in the UK?

Tags: lumber

Ive been searching online for a few days on places to buy 3 or 4mm sheets of wood. My only 2 requirements is that it should be at least 3.6m long and no more than than 5mm thick. Am i right in thinking that the only way is to have these made at a saw mill?

Comment: If you're looking at solid wood for whatever it is you're doing you should know that it's likely to warp to hell after being prepared, unless carefully stored "in stick" with weight on top, or completely shielded by wrapping in plastic. What's this for?

Comment: This question is getting voted to close because shopping recommendations (i.e. "where can I buy xxx?") are specifically considered off-topic.  Besides, this is the type of thing that you'd be expected to do yourself as part of "woodworking"; make a board of specific dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll struggle to get anything like this from any of the big DIY stores (Wickes, B&Q etc.) and you'll most likely have to go to a timber supplier such as Brooks Brothers, Howarth, Latham Timber, Timbmet or similar.

You may be able to find a local timber merchant who will supply you with some pieces of this size but you'll find a lot of those are ultimately just resellers for some of the large national timber merchants I've listed above.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like it would be that difficult to make.  You're talking about something 4" wide, 12'+ long and 1/8" thick...You should be able to resaw that on a band saw or even a table saw.  The hardest part will be surfacing the cut off the band saw.

A drum sander would help get you to exact thickness if you need to be precise/consistent.